# How to save history of component in react native using react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react native router flux in android project for routing when i jump from one component to another than the history of last component is remove from stack i want to store components history please anyone.

Answer (score 0):

instead of jump you can use

```
Action.keynameofyournextpage()
```

ex to go to page1 to page2 
can use

```
Actions.page2()
```

in page 1

Comment: i want to store components history how can i store history

Comment: can you please explain what do u mean by component history

Comment: in main-screen have some data and then route to another component but when i route back to main-screen then data is reload again component mount again but i don't want to mount my component again every-time i route. component not reload again when back route to last component sorry for typo

Comment: if you dont want to reload the data again when back to main screen then this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a record of the components, use the `AsyncStorage` module to save them.

Example

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
//set data
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('componenthistory', componenthistory);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
...
//get data
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('componenthistory');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Comment: @ImranAli  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?